# How to add extra data with Universal Links iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, ios-universal-links, nsuseractivity

I am using Deep Linking/ Universal links in my app. So far everything working fine but I would like to know if you can add extra information to these links so when the user taps them I get back are data. I can load data to a server etc if needed?

Thanks!